# Redirect a http request to a website from within an iframe with a Reverse Proxy in front of the site

Tags: html, http, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I am using nginx as a Reverse Proxy in front of a website and intercept download/preview requests for the files stored on the site. The download requests come from within an iframe and if the user is not authorised, I redirect them to the logout page. But this does not take the main page (outside of the iframe) to the logout page. Any idea how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user is not authorised you may want to send a message from the iframe to its parent. On receiving the message you would then redirect the parent window to the logout page. An example implementation is [found here](https://davidwalsh.name/window-iframe).

However this becomes much harder if you are not able to modify the iframe page's source. Since you are using nginx, one solution would be script injection using the `ngx_http_sub_module` module. This module replaces one string in the response with another. Note that this module is not included by default, you may need to build nginx with the `--with-http_sub_module` parameter. See the [module page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html) for more information, including an example.

The iframe needs the line:

```
parent.postMessage( "redirect", "http://www.your-domain.com" );
```

To inject this with nginx you might try:

```
location / {
    sub_filter '</head>' '<script language="javascript">parent.postMessage( "redirect", "http://www.your-domain.com" );</script></head>';
    sub_filter_once on;
}
```

The parent window would need the corresponding code:

```
var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var eventer = window[ eventMethod ];
var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

// Listen to message from child window
eventer( messageEvent, function( e ) {
    // normally if the message was meant to come from your domain
    // you would check e.origin to verify that it's not someone
    // sending messages you don't want
    if ( e.data = "redirect" ) {
        window.location.replace( "your-logout-url" );
    }
}, false );
```

A more advanced solution might include the redirect url in the message; you could then handle the iframe redirecting to different locations.

Comment: The problem here is that I have no control over the website itself. I write modules in the nginx proxy to intercept the requests and take appropriate actions. How will I insert this JS into the iframe or its parent window?

Comment: @user1295872 fair enough. Updated with a nginx code injection solution

Comment: @jla Does `ngx_http_sub_module` work on `https` requests?